# Karate - Authentication - cannot access url address under password

Tags: automated-tests, karate

Using Karate, I have need to use basic authentication (to pass common authentication dialog window with username and password), and I have tried this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-basic-authentication-example).

1. I have created the file basic-auth.js

```
    function fn(creds) {
      var temp = creds.username + ':' + creds.password;
      var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
      var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(temp.bytes);
      return 'Basic ' + encoded;
    }
```

2. I have added the call to the test feature file I run (added to Scenario section):

```
    header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: 'realusernamestring', password: 'realpasswordstring' }
```

3. Then I have placed the url I want to access right after:

```
    driver urlUnderPassword
```

But it did not work, I still cannot access the page. I think there is something missing, something what needs to be done. Could you help me what the problem might be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is for API tests not UI tests.

If you need the browser / driver to do basic auth it should be easy, just put it in the URL: https://intellipaat.com/community/10343/http-basic-authentication-url-with-in-password

So I am guessing something like this will work:

```
* driver 'http://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + urlUnderPassword
```

Comment: confirmed, that worked for me. Thank you.